# jQuery Ajax PHP POST method with response array[] instad sent data. How to get send values in response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am creating simple application which will insert log data into database table.

Going with jQuery Ajax POST method and JSON format for data.

My index.php has HTML and this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.example.com/ajax_model.php",
        data: {
            "log_session": "27738d7552b75ae395ae1138adf4fa60",
            "log_ip": "1.2.3.4",
            "log_vrijeme": "2018-11-23 01:22:47",
            "log_model": "12345"
        },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

My ajax_model.php - which gives me response `Array[]` instad the data which is sent:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($_POST);
    exit;
}
?>
```

I am getting result in my `console.log()` and `alert()` - `Array[]`.
How can I output my sent response to check if the data was correctly sent over Ajax?

Am I missing some brackets like `[]` or `{}`?
Or do I need to add something to my ajax_model.php file?

Thank you for suggestion and provided information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't sending JSON so get rid of:

```
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

That will cause $_POST to be empty as the default `contentType` is:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Woow! It works after I removed the suggested "contentType". I spend two hours figuring out what could I got wrong. Thank you very much

Comment: @KikiFIstrekNovi - You should mark the answer as accepted. It makes it easier for people to find the right answer later and the contributors appreciate it.

Comment: Moreover, I would like to know why did I get the null body in some responses while trying to figure it out? Like, HTTP 200 and status Ok, but response was empty?

Comment: Not really sure to be honest and am also guessing you tried lots of things in the php at same time

Comment: Yes, exactly I did. Maybe messed up something among with it.

Comment: And, yes, forgot to write the SQL part. Ohh, first time for me here. Nevertheless, can I normally parse this kind of data to my databse using the INSERT INTO query to insert the data into my database table?

Comment: Yes. The data sent via ajax is exact same format as if it was a form submittal that populated $_POST. And taking the various parts of that to store in db is standard procedure

Comment: Awesome. I really appreciate your help in resolving the problem and time!